# como fazer agrupamento numa sql

Tags: sql, firebird

Tenho uma SQL que quando executo dá erro. Alguém poderia me ajudar a realizar o agrupamento dessa SQL?

```
select i.ref, r.nome,n.qtde,sum(n.vlr_tot)
  from geitens as i
  inner join gerefer as r on r.cod = i.ref
  inner join gelannfs as n on n.item = i.cod
  inner join gecadnfs as c on c.doc = n.doc
  where c.serie = 'Z' and n.mes = :mes and n.ano = :ano
    and c.mes = :mes and c.ano = :ano group by i.ref order by i.ref
```

Comment: Tentou fazer `GROUP BY i.ref, r.nome,n.qtde`?

Answer (score -1):

Boa tarde, beleza?

Tente agrupar de forma genérica, como eu faço em diversos cases aqui..

**Exemplo :**

```
select i.ref, r.nome,n.qtde,sum(n.vlr_tot) 
from geitens as i 
inner join gerefer as r on r.cod = i.ref 
inner join gelannfs as n on n.item = i.cod 
inner join gecadnfs as c on c.doc = n.doc 
where c.serie = 'Z' 
and n.mes = :mes 
and n.ano = :ano 
and c.mes = :mes 
and c.ano = :ano 
group by 1,2,3,4
order by i.ref
```